# One embedded excel for multiple charts in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, ms-office

I have a ppt with 80+ charts in 50+ slides.

When I get the data, I've to go into each chart -> right click -> Edit data -> Update the data in the embedded excel.

This process I'm repeating 80+ times for each chart which is time consuming.

I'm aware that the ppt can be transformed into a complete excel pack where we can have all the data in one single sheet and link to multiple charts in different tabs.

But, **Is there a possibility in ppt itself to keep all the data in one embedded excel and refer it to all the 80+ charts?**

Really appreciate any help on this!!

Please let me know if you have any questions..

Thanks..

Comment: There is no mention of VBA code in this question. What have you tried so far? Excel or Powerpoint?

Comment: Welcome Anitha! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This post is off topic for Stack Overflow because it does not actually involve coding, better to be asked on SuperUser 
https://superuser.com/

Comment: >> But, Is there a possibility in ppt itself to keep all the data in one embedded excel and refer it to all the 80+ charts?
No. But if you link the charts to PPT, it'll do what you want.